# The database [name] is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer) After company changed server

Tags: sql-server

My company had a new server installed and now I can not access databases. This is the error message:

> The database NewDatabase is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)

and this is what it says under program location:

> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.DatabaseNavigableItem.get_CanGetChildren()

> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)

> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)

I have already tried this solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/dd207004(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

but the step by step solution cant be followed because in step 2 under the server there is no SQL Server Configuration Manager option.

Is there another way to fix it?

Comment: This sounds like you're connected to an instance where the database has since been removed and you are trying to access it via the object explorer.

Comment: So the database is removed and the data that was there is lost?

Comment: Well, presumably whomever removed the database made a backup of it before, or physically moved the files.

Comment: Is that database still on the server? You can check by running select * from sys.databases. This sounds more like a permissions issue than the database going missing.

Comment: Hello Sean, I also think it is a permission issue because when I try to delete a database I get another error which says: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_delete_database_backuphistory', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Comment: Is there a way to fix that permission issue?

Comment: I ran the  select * from sys.databases and the database is still on the server.

Comment: That means you no longer have permission to view definition on that database. If you feel you need that permission you will have to somebody grant you that permission. I would check with somebody on your team (dba group or similar) and ask them.

Comment: Im the one that prevously created the database and then my company set up a new company serven and now all computers have a new "User". I assume I dont have the access because Im logged in with the new "User" that has been added to my computer. Could that be why Im having this issue>